# Design optimizations when making external process calls

Tags: java, linux, oop, design-patterns, processbuilder

I need from a java process to call external processes/scripts/cli commands.
Since these calls will be quite a lot and some will return back the result of the process/script that run and others will just run it, I was wondering if:

1. There is a standard design to build around Java's `ProcessBuilder`
   so that I don't have scattered in the code calls to `ProcessBuilder`
   constantly
2. What optimizations can I do? For example would it make sense to read
   from files all the cli commands instead of keeping them e.g. as
   `final String` in the code?

Comment: Please post some samples of commands

Comment: @Aubin:examples are:restart other processes via `/etc/init.d`,do `ifconfig`, do remote shell to name the most important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little bit vague to write a precise answer but I have some suggestions:

- Shells are designed to link commands (pipe, wait, and so on) and to code a little bit of logic. Shells are interpreted and are very easy to update but have to keep simple. They may be a basic part of your system.
- Write your own `launch` method to start a process and capture stdout and stderr (in two threads), to write a log of your driver.
- Design an XML file to declaratively specify:

  - the processes paths, theirs arguments (static ones)
  - the parallelism and the synchronization between jobs
- Write a model in Java to reflect the XML process model (JAXB may be a solution)
- Add to the model the capability to wait for a set of jobs
- Add modifiers to the model to dynamically change the value of arguments

If I try to classify your problem, I think mainly at *Control flow*.

To resolve a large problem you may use parallelism: launch concurrently several processes and wait for the termination of all of them: it's a *rendez-vous* or *join* phase. You may launch remote command to another networked computer, perhaps.

A good example to how to specify parallelism into an XML file is [ANT build files](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html):

```
<parallel>
  <wlrun ... >
  <sequential>
    <sleep seconds="30"/>
    <junit fork="true" forkmode="once" ... >
    <wlstop/>
  </sequential>
</parallel>
```

Can I suggest you to use ANT to solve your problem without programming?

A drawing of wished execution may help, with a paper and a pen... ;-)

Several graphical applications may help to draw the logical diagram of control flow. Once done, publish it here and you'll obtain more precise answer, I hope...

Comment: +1.This is interesting but some parts I don't follow.What do you mean when you refer to jobs?And what by the `model`?I mean you just suggest reading from an XML configuration file (might be even a properties file) right?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, Jobs are the {Process+meta information like its status, its logical name and so on}. Model is more than 'config-file' because it's a specification of the logic and your program will be an interpreter of this specification. XML is more structured than properties file.

Comment: Also what do you mean about `the parallelism and the synchronization between jobs`? How do I capture that?

Comment: I am still not sure how the parallelism can be specified in the XML files?

Comment: Although I don't have such "heavy" requirements you pointed out things I didn't consider.Also although you have edited the answer, I can not upvote again for the edit.I always thought that re-vote is allowed after an edition...

Comment: You may choose it at the correct answer tomorrow if you agree with my suggestions.